# Template doesn't react to the change of variable React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component in which I want to display another component after form submit.

When I'm running function on form submit I'm changing submitted value to `true` and if I do `console.log(submitted)` it changes to `true` but in the template it is still false so `Alert` component doesn't show up.

I'm trying to learn hooks and maybe the problem with how I'm using them?

My component looks like this

```
export const SignupForm = () => {
    let name:any = handleUserInput('');
    let email:any = handleUserInput('');
    let password:any = handleUserInput('');
    let submitted:any = false;

    function registerUser(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void {

        event.preventDefault();
        submitted = true;
        const registerInfo = Object.assign({}, {
            email: email.value, 
            password: password.value, 
            name: name.value
        });

        axios.post('/register', registerInfo)
            .then(response => {
                errors = response.data.errors
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
    function handleUserInput(initialValue: string): object {
        const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

        function handleChange(event: Event): void {
            let element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
            setValue(element.value);
        }

        return {
            value,
            onChange: handleChange
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: submitted}}></div>
            {submitted ? <Alert /> : ''}

            <div className="form-holder">
                <form action="POST" className="form" onSubmit={(e) => registerUser(e)}>
                    <label htmlFor="Email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" className="form__input" {...email} required />
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" className="form__input" {...password} required />
                    <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" className="form__input" {...name} required />
                    <button type="submit" className="form__button">Signup</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submitted` local variable is assigned asynchronously. This won't result in component update.

It should be:

```
...
const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

function registerUser(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(true);
    ...
```